# Displaying map labels over coordinate grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, grids-graticules, rule-based, composer-manager

My grid overlaps labels placed on a map.

Is there a way of forcing the labels to be displayed in front/on top and the grid placed behind the text?

Despite looking I cannot find a solution.

[image: grid]

Using QGIS 2.18.15

Comment: Are your labels part of the imagery layer or tied to a separate vector layer?

Comment: @JoshC they are a separate line vector layer

Answer (score 2):

Here is an effective workaround using **visibility presets**.

1. In your Layers Panel, select only the vector layer which contains the labels to be visible.
2. It looks like this is already the case in your project, but ensure that any features in this layer are transparent, and that *only* the labels are visible.
3. Under **Manage Layer Visibility** (the eyeball button), select **Add Preset**.
4. Name your new preset `labels`.
5. Now go into your Composer window. Once **Map 0** is positioned how you like it, duplicate it. There's no specific command for this, just copy and paste.
6. Position **Map 1** directly on top of **Map 0**.
7. Under **Map 1** > **Item Properties** > **Layers**, check `Follow visibility preset` and select `labels`.
8. Make sure that your grid is assigned to **Map 0**, and that **Map 1** is listed first in the Items panel.

Note that this solution only works as long as long as both maps are set to the same extent and scale. It's possible to have **Map 1** obtain its extent/scale values from **Map 0**, but this may be more work than it's worth unless you plan to frequently adjust your map in the Composer window.

[image: image of labels over gridlines]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, maybe simpler, is to create your grid as a vector layer, using the "create grid" tool in the processing toolbox. You can then style it exactly as you want, and the labels will automatically go above it (and even avoid it if you want).

Comment: I'd considered that when I was writing up my answer, but the resulting output just doesn't have the same labeling options as a composer grid. Having the grid labels outside the box, for example, is impossible when using a vector layer.